# Separating key and IV in AES encryption in objective-c

Tags: c#, objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm trying to convert my AES-encryption class from c# to objective-c(I'm quite newbie to objective-c) and a bit confused about one thing. I'm creating my key and initialization vector objects from a single transferred object like this in c#:

```cs
Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
KeySize = 256;
Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(transferredObject.Substring(x1, x2));
IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(transferredObject.Substring(y1, y2));
```

Where x & y are int values, that represent certain range and transferredObject is String. Add then I can use Key & IV for encryption/decryption process.

I know, that in objective-c I should use this method:

```c
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
key, kCCKeySizeAES256, iv,
[self bytes], dataLength,
buffer, bufferSize,
&numBytesEncrypted);
```

for encryption and similar method for decryption, but I can't find a way, how to get my key & iv objects. The examples for objective-c usually show something like:

```c
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So, how can I get my key & IV if I have the same single `NSString * transferredObject` object in objective-c?

---

The solution in accepted answer will work.
Another solution is to use NSString substringToIndex method.

Will look like this:

```c
NSString* IV = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x1, x2)];
NSString* Key = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(y1, y2)];

char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));

[IV getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

[Key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];

CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength,
                                          buffer, bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
- (BOOL)getBytes:(void *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxBufferCount usedLength:(NSUInteger *)usedBufferCount encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding options:(NSStringEncodingConversionOptions)options range:(NSRange)range remainingRange:(NSRangePointer)leftover
```

Example:

```
int keyLength = kCCKeySizeAES256, x1=0, x2=keyLength;
int ivLength = kCCBlockSizeAES128, y1=keyLength, y2=ivLength;
u_int8_t key[keyLength*2];
u_int8_t iv[ivLength*2];
BOOL keySuccess = [transferredObject getBytes:key maxLength:keyLength usedLength:NULL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(x1, x2) remainingRange:NULL];
BOOL ivSuccess = [transferredObject getBytes:iv maxLength: ivLength usedLength:NULL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(y1, y2) remainingRange:NULL];
```

buffer:
A buffer into which to store the bytes from the receiver. The returned bytes are not NULL-terminated.

maxBufferCount:
The maximum number of bytes to write to buffer.

usedBufferCount:
The number of bytes used from buffer. **Pass NULL** if you do not need this value.

encoding:
The encoding to use for the returned bytes.

options:
A mask to specify options to use for converting the receiver’s contents to encoding (if conversion is necessary). You can pass `NULL`.

range:
The range of characters in the receiver to get.

leftover:
The remaining range. **Pass NULL** If you do not need this value.

Comment: Yeah, that'll work. Interesting. Actually, I've solved that issue by simply using `[transferredObject substringWithRange:NSMakeRange()]` method, the CCCrypt method will act correctly if Key and IV would be of NSString type. But your solution will also work.